# Fruit detection - No matching function for call to 'cv::SimpleBlobDetector::SimpleBlobDetector(cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params&)'

Tags: c++, opencv, blob, object-detection

Currently I'm trying to use OpenCV for fruit detector project with camera. I take the source code from https://github.com/JackThePie/fruit-detector. I use QT Creator app in Ubuntu. I am new to OpenCV can someone help me with this issue? Note: I use OpenCV-MinGW-Build-OpenCV-4.5.0-with-contrib library which I am sure it is OpenCV2.

This is some part of my .cpp file for Blob detection.

```
// Blob detection
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    // Capture the video from web cam
    VideoCapture capture(filename1); 
    // If not success, exit program
    if (!capture.isOpened())  
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
    }

    namedWindow("Ustawienia Blob", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window called "Ustawienia Blob"
    int colour = 10;
    int iLowTresh = 0;
    int iHighTresh = 300;
    int minArea = 150;
    int minCirc = 0.1;
    int minConv = 0.087;
    int minInertia = 0.0001;

    // Create trackbars in "Ustawienia Blob" window
    createTrackbar("Colour", "Ustawienia Blob", &colour, 255); //Hue (0 - 179)
    createTrackbar("minTresh", "Ustawienia Blob", &iLowTresh, 100); //Hue (0 - 179)
    createTrackbar("maxTresh", "Ustawienia Blob", &iHighTresh, 700);
    createTrackbar("minArea", "Ustawienia Blob", &minArea, 700); //Saturation (0 - 255)
    createTrackbar("minCirc", "Ustawienia Blob", &minCirc, 200); //Value (0 - 255)
    createTrackbar("minConv", "Ustawienia Blob", &minConv, 200);
    createTrackbar("minInertia", "Ustawienia Blob", &minInertia, 100);

    while (true)
    {
        Mat imgOriginal;
        // Read a new frame from video
        bool bSuccess = capture.read(imgOriginal); 
        // If not success, break loop
        if (!bSuccess) 
        {
            break;
        }
        // Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
        SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;

        params.filterByColor = true;
        params.blobColor = colour;

        // Change thresholds
        params.minThreshold = iLowTresh;
        params.maxThreshold = iHighTresh;

        // Filter by Area
        params.filterByArea = true;
        params.minArea = minArea;

        // Filter by Circularity
        params.filterByCircularity = true;
        params.minCircularity = minCirc;

        // Filter by Convexity
        params.filterByConvexity = true;
        params.minConvexity = minConv;

        // Filter by Inertia
        params.filterByInertia = true;
        params.minInertiaRatio = minInertia;

        // Set up detector with params

        SimpleBlobDetector detector(params); //HERE WHERE THE ERROR IS
        // Storage for blobs
        std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

        // Detect blobs
        detector.detect(imgOriginal, keypoints);

        // Draw detected blobs as red circles.
        // DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS flag ensures
        // the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob

        Mat im_with_keypoints;
        drawKeypoints(imgOriginal, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0,0,255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS );

        QImage qigm=MatToQImage(imgOriginal);
        image=imgOriginal.clone();
        ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qigm).scaledToWidth(ui->label->size().width(),Qt::FastTransformation));

        QImage qigm2=MatToQImage(im_with_keypoints);
        image=im_with_keypoints.clone();
        ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qigm2).scaledToWidth(ui->label->size().width(),Qt::FastTransformation));

        // Wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
        if (waitKey(30) == 27) 
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the code, there is an error occur in line :

```
SimpleBlobDetector detector(params);
```

The error is stated in the picture [Line 147](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM2Bu.png)

Thank You!

I try to find the solution here https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html#details but cannot find any solution..

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: this seems relate to some lack of include libraries. Did you add `#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>`